# Где ошибка в представлении MS SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server

Уже устал копаться в интернете и тыркать всё подряд методом тыка. Переношу запросы MS Access в представления MS SQL.

Часть кода представления выглядит так:

```
SELECT ... , IIf([MTR].[Способ выполнения]>2 And [MTR].[Цех]>0,21381,21382) AS Выражение2 FROM MTR;
```

При создании представления или проверке синтаксиса sql - получаю ошибку:

**Неверный синтаксис около конструкции ">"**

Comment: попробуйте так CASE WHEN [MTR].[Способ выполнения] > 2 And [MTR].[Цех] > 0 THEN 21381 ELSE 21382 END AS Выражение2

Comment: Не экономьте на скобках... `IIf( ([MTR].[Способ выполнения] > 2) And ([MTR].[Цех] > 0) , 21381 , 21382 )`

Comment: @AzizUmarov Благодарю! То что нужно!

Comment: @Akina Неа, не хочет ни в какую через IIf работать. Через CASE сработало как надо! Благодарю за совет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
CASE WHEN [MTR].[Способ выполнения] > 2 And [MTR].[Цех] > 0 THEN 21381 ELSE 21382 END AS Выражение2
```